# Js array returns always the highest value

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var max_value = function(array) {
  var result = array[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > result) {
      result = array[i];
    };
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(max_value([1, 10, 9]));
```

this returns 10 either like this:

```
console.log(max_value([1, 10, 9]));
```

or

```
console.log(max_value([10, 1, 9]));
```

if the condition is true should the last array number be returned? (9 in the last case, it seems like the highest number is returned)

Comment: Hmm. you are not checking with the previous value to the current. But the previously stored highest value.

Comment: why should be `9` returned?

Comment: That condition will never be true because if you're comparing result, which is 10, with array[3], which is 9. 10 is higher than 9 that's why that function you have will always return the highest.

Comment: because of  if (array[i] > result) , as you iterate through each item, the one with the highest value will be assigned to result so you will always get the highest number.

Comment: the function is designed to return always the highest value in an array and judging by your question it's working, so what's the problem?

Comment: result records higher value from 2 sequence ints in array. then next sequence int is compared to result (not to previous int)

Comment: in last case, 10 would never be smaller than 9 or any other item in array, then how 9 could be assigned to result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the native `Array.protoype.sort` to do the hard work for you.

```js
var max_value = function(array) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => a - b).pop()
}
console.log(max_value([1, 10, 9, 5, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4]));
```

Comment: sorting is (in the best case) **O(nlogn)**, but you need only **O(n)** with one loop. btw, the op has not stated, what he is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var arrV = [9,10,2]
console.log(Math.max(...arrV));
```

One more suggestion you can use short hand operator

```
 var arrV = [9,10,2]
 console.log(Math.max(...arrV));
```